# show/hide div conditionally

Tags: javascript, html

i want to hide the div below when the user select "laptop" just by using vanilla javascript

```
<select class="form-control input-lg" name="category">
      <option value="Desktop PCs &amp; Central unit">Desktop PCs &amp; Central unit</option>
      <option value="Laptop">Laptop</option>
    </select>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="" for="Name">Name</label>
      <input type="text"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: mmm, the use of classList is not implemented in all browsers, anyway take a look for it https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: What did you tried already ? Can you show the code ?

Comment: You can do this using JQuery too!

Comment: Please do share your code that you have tried so far. That will help people to solve your issues better :)

Comment: i have no code am just wondering if there's a way to hide that div on a select using vanilla javascript

Comment: what div are you trying to hide?

Comment: the div with the class "form-group"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can attach *change* event to the select element with *addEventListener()*. Inside the event handler function check the value, if it is *Laptop* then set the *display* property to *none* else set the property value to *block*.

Try the following way:

```js
var element = document.querySelector("div.form-group");

document.querySelector('select[name=category]').addEventListener('change', function(){
  if(this.value == 'Laptop')
    element.style.display = 'none';
  else
    element.style.display = 'block';
})
```

```html
<select class="form-control input-lg" name="category">
  <option value="Desktop PCs &amp; Central unit">Desktop PCs &amp; Central unit</option>
  <option value="Laptop">Laptop</option>
</select>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="" for="Name">Name</label>
  <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

Comment: yup that's work thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Scripts, you are most welcome :)

Comment: This works great here, but when I test it in a an app with a separate html and js file, the name input always shows.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, tested this myself and it works fine...

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function hideDiv(elem) {
    if(elem.value == "Laptop")
 document.getElementById('hideDiv').style.display = "none";
    else
        document.getElementById('hideDiv').style.display = 'block';
}
</script>

<select class="form-control input-lg" onchange="hideDiv(this)" name="category">
  <option value="Desktop PCs &amp; Central unit">Desktop PCs &amp; Central unit</option>
  <option value="Laptop">Laptop</option>
</select>

<div id="hideDiv" class="form-group">
  <label class="" for="Name">Name</label>
  <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks that's work fine it  does look easy only when you see the code xD